# trying to learn while solving some basic haskell problems

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and trying out some exercise.While trying to load the below code i am getting a binding error  howmanytwoequal function.Can anyone please tell me as to what mistake i had done.

```
howmayoftwoequal :: Int->Int->Int
howmanyoftwoequal m n
        |m==n =1
        |otherwise =0

howmanyequal::Int->Int->Int->Int
howmanyequal m n o
        | howmanyoftwoequal m n && howmanyoftwoequal n o  =3
        | howmanyoftwoequal m n || howmanyoftwoequal n o =2
        |otherwise =1
```

Comment: Since Haskell is sort-of white-space sensitive, please edit your question to display the indentation your code has.

Comment: even more importantly, Haskell is newline/semicolon sensitive even!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. Typo in howmanyoftwoequal type definition: you have 'howmayoftwoequal' instead of 'howmanyoftwoequal'
2. To use howmanyoftwoequal in boolean operations && and || its type should be Bool:

   ```
   howmanyoftwoequal :: Int->Int->Bool
   howmanyoftwoequal m n = m==n
   ```

Comment: Also, of course, you can then replace howmanyoftwoequal with just "==". Incidentally standard Haskell style is to use camelCase: howManyOfTwoEqual

Comment: @user3274335 please accept this answer then - I noticed that you did not accept any of your questions so far so please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers too

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `howManyEqual` misses the case where `m == o` but `m == n || n == o` does not hold, which it seems should also be a valid case for it returning `2`.

If you are trying to return the size of the largest equivalence class between `m`, `n`, and `o`, this can be achieved as follows:

```
largestEquivSize :: [Int] -> Int
largestEquivSize = maximum . map length . group . sort

howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEqual m n o = largestEquivSize [m, n, o]
```

With the added bonus that `largestEquivSize` is a lot more general (in fact its type is unnecessarily constrained here, and could be `Ord a => [a] -> Int`).